# Java Paint Application

Tags: java, swing, paint

I've been working on a Java Paint application for practice; however, the part I'm stuck at right now is how to change the color of my pen without changing the color of anything I have previously drawn? I've been advised to create another ArrayList and incorporate it into my paintComponent but now I'm confused and unsure of what to do. Can anyone help me? I didn't include my tester class but it has the buttons created already, this is just what my code does far.

```
package drawing;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Drawing extends JPanel {

private final ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean drawingInProgress;
private Color shapeColor = Color.BLACK;

public void setShapeColor(Color color)
{
this.shapeColor = color;
}

public Drawing(){
setBackground(Color.white);
drawingInProgress = false;
addMouseListener(
    new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev)
    {
        if(!drawingInProgress)
    {
        drawingInProgress = true;
    } else {
            drawingInProgress = false;
        }            
    }        

    }
);    

addMouseMotionListener(
new MouseMotionAdapter(){
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
{
    if (drawingInProgress){
        points.add(event.getPoint());
        repaint();
    } else {           
    }

}
}       
);    
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);
//g.setColor(shapeColor); What I had before that was wrong.
for (Point point: points)
g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 8, 8);
}

public void red() {
    shapeColor = Color.RED;
repaint();
}

public void blue() {
shapeColor = Color.BLUE;
repaint();

}

public void green() {
shapeColor = Color.GREEN;
repaint();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create pseudo "shape" which carries not just the information it needs to paint it self, but also the color (and any other properties)

```
public interface PaintShape {
    public Rectangle getBounds();
    public Color getColor();
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d);
}
```

Then you can create what ever shapes you want...

```
public abstract class AbstractPaintShape implements PaintShape {

    private final Rectangle bounds;
    private final Color color;

    public AbstractPaintShape(Rectangle bounds, Color color) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}

public class OvalPaintShape extends AbstractPaintShape {

    private Ellipse2D oval;

    public OvalPaintShape(Rectangle bounds, Color color) {
        super(bounds, color);
        oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(bounds.getX(), bounds.getY(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(getColor());
        g2d.fill(oval);
    }

}
```

Or something similar

You should take a closer look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for more ideas

Answer (score 0):

One way to go would be to create a class like `MyShape` consisting of a list of points (like you already have) and a color.

For the whole painting you would have a list of such `MyShape` objects.

Now whenever the user begins to draw a line (i.e. mouse-down) you'd create a new `MyShape` object with the current color and collect all the mouse movements in the points list of the object until mouse-up.

In `repaint` you'd paint all MyShape's in the list of shapes, each with it's own color.

Answer (score 0):

In this case where you store the points and repaint the list of points, you would have to save the color of each `Point` with the point information, and then upon drawing ask each point what color it is. Perhaps create a class `ColoredPoint` that also has a `Color`.

```
for (ColoredPoint cp : points) {
  g.setColor(cp.getColor());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor this to store the shapes separately to what draws them.

```
public class Shape {

    private final ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    public final Color color;

    public Shape() {
        this(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public Shape(final Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void addPoint(final Point point) {
        this.points.add(point);
    }

    public List<Point> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

Your drawing class would then have

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel {
    private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>():

    // ...
    // a mouse listener that creates shapes and gives them points
    // ...

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Shape shape: shapes
            g.setColor(shape.color);
            for (Point point: shape.getPoints()) {
                g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 8, 8);
            }
        }
    }
```